# How to set a HTTPS Java servlet on glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, https, glassfish, raspberry-pi3

I successfully deployed a Java servlet on glassfish5 in my Raspberry PI3.
Now I wanted to use another servlet for a Telegram bot, but in this case I need to use HTTPS.

I tried to define a new servlet with  in the web.xml, but when I try to reach the servlet via https connection from a browser the result is an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

My servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONArray;

@WebServlet("/telegramUpdate")

public class TelegramUpdate extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TelegramUpdate() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doGet");

    }

    protected void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("doPost");

    }

}
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Smarthome</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>telegram webhook</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/telegramMessage</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

In case it be a raspberry config problem, this is the result of netcat -lptn

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs$ netstat -lptn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8686                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::4848                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::3700                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::8181                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::1527                 :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

443 port is not mentioned, but in case it is closed I don't know how to open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with port 8181 which is the default port for secured communication on Payara and Glassfish. 
Please also see here: https://blog.payara.fish/securing-payara-server-with-custom-ssl-certificate

Comment: Which URL did you try?

Comment: Just realised that I misread your post. You are using Glassfish and not Payara. Somehow I mixed this up. However port 8181 should still be the secured one

Comment: Actually, I wondered why you referred to Payara and I thought that Payara and Glassfish shared this behaviour. In any case the url I tried was https://<ip>:8181/Smarthome-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/telegramUpdate

Comment: Payara is meant as a drop-in replacement for Glassfish so the two should behave the same in most cases. Isn't there a message in the log file with the URL that the application is deployed to?

Comment: No I mean normally the URL for the app should be  logged

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202974/discussion-between-sthor69-and-christoph-john).

Comment: You were right. I forgot opening port 8181 in the firewall. Unfortunately there is a bug in glassfish5 for htpps. Switching to python...

Comment: Did you try with Glassfish 5.1 or Payara? The latter usually has more bug fixes and is updated regularly. You should be able to simply replace GF by Payara.